# IPs insead URLs in sources-list

Tags: repository

It's possible use IPs instead of URLs for the repositories in sources.list?

*(And how)*

Comment: It's wrong. Don't do it. URLs won't always point to the same IP address.

Comment: can be useful to avoid DNS hack

Comment: If a server with a single IP address serves multiple sites over HTTP, it relies on the name to know which site to serve. So this isn't guaranteed to work, it's on a case by case basis. FTP protocol (ftp://, not http: //ftp.... ) should always work though.

Comment: If you put the IP address  in /etc/hosts along the original name then you don't rely on DNS anymore but still get a working site, since HTTP gave the name to the server.

Comment: can show an example of what put in  */etc/hosts*?

Comment: got problems with suspicious DNS activity recently, so avoid rely on it in something important such as the core updates

Comment: Doesn't matter. Even if you get a MITM attack from DNS, the repositories, including package file checksum, are signed with a GPG key. This can't lead to apt-get installing a fake package.

Comment: but it don't asked me for a GPG key

Comment: It was installed when the OS was installed, and then kept up to date. For Debian, explanations there: https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt

Comment: any ways, can give an example of how to set it for other IPs plz? web-browser stills a breach..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#File_content

Comment: Looks like this question is a big [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) anyway.

Comment: thx for the answers. So /etc/hosts & iptables are a solution for DNS hacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IP instead of an url in your sources.list.

here is an example: To convert `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main`, you need to get the ip of the url, but in this case it is a redirector! . The right URL to convert is [the url of the debian mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) e,g: `ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/`

```
nslookup ftp2.de.debian.org
```

Use `dig`, `nslookup` ... to get the IP address

sample output:

```
...

Non-authoritative answer:
ftp2.de.debian.org      canonical name = ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de.
Name:   ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
Address: 137.226.34.46
Name:   ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
Address: 2a00:8a60:e012:a00::21
```

then edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://137.226.34.46/debian buster main
```

The debian security repository:

```
deb http://20.49.228.237/debian-security/ buster/updates main
```

Comment: thx for answer. Know how get the mirror for security updates? "security.debian.org"

Comment: it says *"does not have a Release file"*

Comment: @user406126 I have edited my answer.

Comment: that security IP pertains to Microsoft, not Debian foundation. There's any source where can lookup the mirrors myself?